# Mute Line-In in vista

Tags: windows-vista, sound-card, speakers, ps3

I have plugged my ps3 sound to play through the line in on my computer to play through my computer speakers and it makes this annoying static noise as was wondering if it is possible to mute the line in only in vista to prevent this annoying static noise when the ps3 is not in use.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Try Right-clicking the speaker icon in the system tray and selecting "Recording Devices"
- Select "Line In" and then click the "Properties" button.
- There should be a "Levels" tab, where you can adjust the volume.

If that isn't a simple solution for you (as I believe the Levels tab is only there when a signal is present), you could always solve the problem with hardware.  A cheap and simple A/B switch should work great.